# iOS NSMutableArray sticking

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to populate a `UITableView` from an array that contains files in a directory

```
//in my header
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *files;
//in my tableView:cellForRow:atIndexPath:
static NSString *cellid = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellid];
    cell.textLabel.text = [_files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
```

(`_files` is set equal to `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[self downloadsDir];` prior to this method being called) This works, and shows the correct files. 
The problem is if I add a file to the directory, and then use `tableView reloadData`, a new file will be added, but the title will be a duplicate of another file. Example

table view before adding file

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
text.txt
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
testing.txt
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

table view after adding file `othertest.txt`

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
text.txt
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
testing.txt
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
testing.txt
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

it should be

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
text.txt
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
testing.txt
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
othertest.txt
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

if I restart the app, it will show the correct files. But for some reason it does this. Anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellid];
    cell.textLabel.text = [_files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
```

You're not setting the cell label text except for when you allocate a new cell. Try this instead:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellid];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [_files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

Same code, but I've moved the line where you set the cell's text so that it gets executed when you reuse a cell as well as when you create a new one.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'll mark it as correct when they let me.

Comment: Very common problem. Glad to help.